# How do I allow access to a folder only if the content is embedded on another site?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

I have a site on a.example.com which is a web application to which I cannot, for many reasons, upload media files.

I want to be able to upload these files to b.example.com/media/ (an Apache/PHP server) so that one is only able to access the files on the /media/ folder through `<img>, <media>, <a>` and other elements on pages found on a.example.com.

I've tried an .htaccess inside the /media/ folder with `Require host` and `Require forward-dns a.example.com`, but this just denies basically all requests.

What else can I try?

Thank you all in advance for your help & time!

Comment: On site a, proxy `/media/` to site b.  This way site a becomes a client to site b, downloads the media files and returns them to the initial client.

Comment: @Nic3500 is correct, such internal proxy is the only reliable approach. Your own approach has to fail, you did not understand how web applications work. It is the web browser that requests the files if you use a simple reference, not the server that delivered the html markup that contains the references. The only other alternative would be to evaluate the referrer headers, but that is not reliable, can easily get spoofed.